# ¿Qué significa la expresión "A lo que te truje chencha"?

Tags: modismos, definiciones, expresiones, méxico

¿Cuál es el significado de la expresión "A lo que te truje chencha"?

Comment: Jamás había escuchado esa expresión. ¿En dónde se utiliza?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Pues aquí en México se utiliza mas no estoy seguro en que contexto y con que significado por eso la pregunta.

Comment: Ah, gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Como muchos países del mundo, México es un país muy rico en cuanto a dichos, refranes y expresiones en general. Dudo que este sea uno que se use en algún otro lugar pero seguro en todos lados se dice algo que significa lo mismo.

Comment: @SergioRomero es cierto. Pensando en un equivalente aqupi en Colombia, *¡A lo que vinimos!* es muy común aquí.

Comment: Ponte a hacer a lo que vienes y no otra cosa.

Comment: Truje quiere decir traje, de traer. Se encuentra en el español de los siglos XVI y XVII, particularmente en obras de Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra y en Pedro Calderón de la Barca, por ejemplo. Y si, acertadamente han opinado algunos se aplica para instruir que se haga lo indicado y no más.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Español**

Puede tener dos singificados:

1. No te metas en lo que no te importa.
2. Concéntrate en lo que estás haciendo y no te distraigas.

Mis padres solían decirme eso todo el tiempo mientras hacía mi tarea. Si de repente volteaba a ver la televisión mi mamá me diría "A lo que te truje chencha" y regresaría a ver mis libros.

**English**

It could have a couple of meanings:

1. Mind your own business.
2. Focus on what you are supposed to do and do not get distracted.

My parents used to say that a lot. If I had to do my homework and suddenly turned to watch the TV screen my mom would snap "*A lo que te truje chencha*!" so I would turn back to face my homework.

Comment: Preferimos usar el español siempre que sea posible según nuestro [FAQ]. Te animo a que traduzcas tu respuesta.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con tu respuesta, es como "has lo que tengas que hacer y nada mas"

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Sergio, ¿sabes si se usa en alguna zona en particular de México o es una expresión común en todo el país?

Comment: @Alpha: Con certeza te puedo decir que se usa en el centro del país, particularmente en el Distrito Federal. Casi estoy seguro que es común en todos lados, pero no lo se a ciencia cierta.

Comment: Cabría completar la respuesta aclarando el significado de _truje_, una forma arcáica de pretérito simple del verbo _traer_, y _chencha_ que -corríjanme- parece ser el diminutivo de un nombre propio (Vicenta, Inocencia...?)

Comment: Estoy en completo desacuerdo, eso no significa "a lo que te truje chencha". La frase va encaminada a hacer algo que ya sabemos debemos estar haciendo [en tu ejemplo] o empezar a hacer algo ya planeado.

Answer (score 5):

Esta frase va dirigida a una actividad previamente planeada.

Te invito a un restaurante y ya nos sirvieron te voy a decir:

> A lo que te truje Chencha!

El ejemplo que pusieron era que estaba estudiando, ¿qué es lo que se supone que debería estar haciendo? Estudiando, entonces, **no significa: "pon atención"; significa: "haz lo que debes estar haciendo"**.

Otro ejemplo, vamos a una fiesta y ya empezó la música y como no nos paramos a bailar yo te digo:

> A lo que te truje Chencha!

¿A qué fuimos a la fiesta? ¿a bailar no? Entonces bailemos.

La frase la tiene que decir la persona que planeó la actividad y se dice justo antes de comenzar como diciendo:

> Pues vamos, empecemos.

Ya sabemos a lo que vamos y si no lo sabemos, el que planeó todo sigue estando en posición de decir esa frase, ejemplo.

> -A lo que te truje Chencha.
>
> -¿Cómo venimos aquí?
>
> -Sí, venimos a echar brinco [una forma coloquial de decir bailar]

La frase es un modo de hablar rústico. "Truje" es un arcaísmo de "traje" conjugación de "traer" y Chencha es diminutivo de Crecencia o Inocencia, del mismo modo en que Pancho es diminutivo de Francisco.

La frase escrita "correctamente" [Está entrecomillado porque a pesar de ser un modo de hablar considerado inculto, es una frase compuesta que **todos** la usan igual] sería:

> A lo que te traje Crecencia.

Answer (score 3):

*A lo que te truje Chencha* es una expresión, probablemente muy antigua, difícil de determinar su origen, que en un principio es muy probable que se utilizara en el centro del país, pero en la actualidad es utilizada ya prácticamente en toda la República mexicana, incluso entre los inmigrantes mexicanos que se encuentran en los estados Unidos y otros países, gracias a los medios masivos de comunicación que la han echo muy popular a través de los años, al utilizarla en las revistas, comics, periódicos, en los argumentos de películas, programas de radio y television, actualmente con el Internet, etc., y significa *a lo que te traje Chencha*, con la característica deformación del lenguaje de ciertos grupos de indígenas y grupos sociales del centro del país, se refiere a exigir a una persona que se ponga realizar de inmediato lo que se fue a hacer a un lugar determinado.

Answer (score 2):

If I go shopping to buy a dress and I start looking at shoes or other merchandise my husband will say "A lo que te truje Chencha".

This means:

> You came to buy shoes, let's buy the shoes and go!

Answer (score 0):

Sólo como nota, puede acortarse: "¡A lo que te truje!" y efectivamente, quiere decir que uno se limite a hacer lo que fue a hacer a un lugar determinado. Normalmente, a comer.

Answer (score 0):

It's like saying “C’mon hurry up and do what you came here to do.”

I'm from México and I’ve heard this phrase all my life. I think originally it says something with sexual connotations referring to a woman named *Chencha*.