# Diferencias regionales en las conjugaciones de los verbos

Tags: verbos, diferencias-regionales, conjugación, formas-irregulares

El otro día leía un comentario en este sitio que usaba "learnt" y por un segundo pensé que estaba mal escrito. Como español aprendí un inglés con grandes influencias británicas pero cuando vine a Estado Unidos re-aprendrí a usar "learned", que es la forma que se favorece aquí.

Ya sabemos que en español sucede lo mismo, y algunos dirían

> Conduce su coche pardo mientras habla por el móvil

y otros

> Maneja su carro café mientras platica por el celular.

Mi pregunta es, ¿llegan las diferencias regionales en el español también a las conjugaciones de los verbos? Sé que hay diferencias en el *significado* de algunos verbos, pero pregunto específicamente por diferencias al formar alguna de las conjugaciones (como el caso de "Learnt/Learned" en inglés) ya sea favoreciendo formas distintas o que en una variante el verbo sea irregular y en otra no.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a cosas como que en España diríamos "sí, ya he terminado de comer" mientras que en Hispanoamérica dirían "sí, ya terminé de comer"?

Comment: Aparte del voseo, es posible que en algunos lugares haya preferencia por una forma u otra en los verbos que tienen dos participios (*imprimido* / *impreso*). Más allá de esto, no se me ocurre nada.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo no, más bien a que en un sito se diga algo como "no creo que **quepa** ahí" y en otro "no creo que **caba** ahí", por exagerarlo mucho. La duda me vino con _learned/learned_, viendo que en un lado del charco se trataba como irregular y en otro no, así que me picó la curiosidad sobre este efecto en español. No favorecer un tiempo verbal sobre otro, si no una declinación distinta. A mi solo se me ocurren ejemplos con verbos irregulares, pero viendo también respuestas como la de walen parece que existe este efecto en diferentes formas. A ver si alguien aporta otra respuesta más...

Comment: En Chile muchas veces usamos el indicativo en vez del subjuntivo del verbo "ir" en este tipo de frases: _Cuidado, no te vas a caer_ (en vez de _no te vayas a caer_), o _Dame la mano, no nos vamos a perder_ (en lugar de _no nos vayamos a perder_). Sé que es un error, pero está bien arraigado. No sé si es una diferencia regional o es algo que pasa en todas partes.

Comment: @Rodrigo, ese ejemplo puede ser también una respuesta válida. Si sacas un poco de tiempo pon una por favor (yo podría poner una _community wiki_ con ese contenido, pero creo que es mejor si lo haces tú, que puedes explicar mejor este caso particular y expandir un poco más. Además es tu privilegio porque esos datos los estás aportando tú).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El verbo *traer* tiene una fuerte diferencia regional. En el español estándar solo se acepta una, no obstante, para mí no hay razón por desaconsejar el uso de la otra forma ya que era la forma más usada en el pasado y nunca se dejó de usar, obviamente.

En fin, *traer* en el pretérito indefinido (o pretérito perfecto simple) tiene la raíz fuerte **traj-** en la gramática normativa.

Pero antiguamente era *trux-* que evolucionó a **truj-** que sigue disfrutando de uso en algunas regiones del mundo, aunque como ya mencioné, no forma parte del habla culta.

Comment: Por ejemplo "Dónde está?" "Lo siento no lo traje / _truje_"? Investigando un poco veo que se favorece en ciertas regiones. De hecho ha aparecido ya por aquí en  la pregutna sobre el mexicanismo ["¿Qué significa la expresión “A lo que te truje chencha”?"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2899/5481) y en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19287/5481) de otra pregunta. Este podría ser un ejemplo perfecto de lo que estaba buscando!

Comment: @Diego exactamente. Puedo añadir algún ejemplo en un momento

Comment: @diego también lo interesante de *traer* es su plena irregularidad en la península. En portugués, opta por una o (la u no se pronuncia  como tal en muchos dialectos): *troux-*. En asturiano, según región, es incluso posible encontrar las cinco vocales: *trax-*, *trex-*, *trix-*, *trox-* y *trux-* (!) aunque muy infrecuentes son *-e-* e *-i-*.

Answer (score 7):

Se me acaba de ocurrir que un caso claro, aunque particualr,  sería el [voseo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo).

Debido al voseo se admiten las formas

- tú **cantas** (estándar singular)
- vos **cantáis** (Voseo tipo I singular)
- vos **cantás** (Voseo tipo III singular)
- tú **cantái** (Voseo tipo II singular)

Que serían una conjugación distinta debido a una diferencia regional. No es exactamente lo que buscaba con mi regunta, pero se me acaba de ocurrir y creo que merece la pena mencionarse.

Comment: Creo que tu respuesta justamente es el ejemplo más fácil y notable entre regiones. El voseo es intercambiado por otras conjugaciones en otras regiones. Por ejemplo en México, sería tu cantas, el canta, ustedes cantan. ¡Gran respuesta!

Comment: El voseo rioplatense es muy peculiar: _vos cantás_, _vos tenés_.

Answer (score 7):

En la zona de Logroño y en las provincias vascongadas no es raro el uso del condicional simple en vez del pretérito imperfecto: «si yo te *contaría*» en vez de «si yo te *contara*»

Comment: Gracias por la contribución y bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas en el futuro!

Comment: El reemplazo del pretérito del subjuntivo por el condicional parece ser una tendencia común; en Argentina lo escucho con cada vez mayor frecuencia.

Comment: @pablodf76 está pasando en otras lenguas ibéricas también.  Es curioso como el castellano, portugués, asturiano y gallego todos comparten este mismo rasgo. (yo incluso en portugués he escuchado una alternancia entre condicional y pluscuamperfecto en una misma oración con estructura paralela, tipo «Se fosse assim, eu ligá-lo-ia e falara sobre o assunto».

Answer (score 6):

En Chile está bastante arraigado el uso del indicativo en vez del subjuntivo del verbo "ir" en este tipo de frases:

> Cuidado, no te **vas** a caer. (En vez de "no te *vayas* a caer")
>
> Dame la mano, no nos **vamos** a perder. (En lugar de "no nos *vayamos* a perder")

Answer (score 4):

Si preguntas por el uso real de los verbos, aunque según la RAE sea incorrecto, tengo un par de ejemplos de España:

- En el norte de Galicia se usa el pretérito de subjuntivo en lugar del pretérito perfecto simple: «ayer *fuéramos* a la playa» en vez de «ayer fuimos a la playa».
- En la zona de Murcia se usa el presente de subjuntivo en el mismo caso: «ayer *cenemos* en casa de Paco» en lugar de «ayer cenamos en casa de Paco».

Hay otros similares. No son cambios que apliquen a todos los verbos (igual que no todos los verbos se conjugan igual), y por supuesto no está aceptado por la RAE, pero son usos lo suficientemente extendidos como para que aparezcan en las secciones de vulgarismos y usos incorrectos, en diferentes tratados.

No sé si es lo que buscas.

Comment: El caso de Galicia es, en realidad, una interferencia del gallego. Originalmente, la forma *fuéramos* no era imperfecto de subjuntivo, sino pluscuamperfecto simple de indicativo. Con el tiempo cambió el uso y ese es el motivo por el cual hoy tenemos dos formas de imperfecto de subjuntivo; pero en gallego no se ha producido el cambio y es por esto que algunos gallegos cometen ese error al hablar en castellano.

Comment: No sé yo tampoco si es lo que buscaba, pero me parece la mar de interesante. Básicamente, en eso ejemplo se toma prestada la conjugación de un tiempo verbal diferente. Por que si entiendo bien, en ambos ejemplos alguien intenta usar el pretérito (un tiempo _anterior_) a base de usar la declinación de un tiempo verbal distinto.

Comment: @Gorpik tampoco se considera error en castellano (siempre que se pueda reemplazar por el pluscuamperfecto, si se debió emplear el indefinido error lo es). Lo mismo se puede escuchar de los asturhablantes (y tal vez con sus vocales elevadas, parecida al caso de Murcia): *nado/nades/nada/nadamos/nadáis/naden* en el indicativo, por ejemplo, y el indefinido también tiene *nademos*) pero sería totalmente interferencia lingüística

Comment: Las formas pluscuamperfectas con *-ra-* son comunes al gallego y al portugués. En este último sólo se usan en textos literarios y formales, no sé cuál sea el caso en gallego.

Comment: Los regionalismos suelen resultar de interferencias.

Comment: @pablodf76 la forma con *-ra* sigue viva en el habla gallega.

Answer (score 3):

En el español neomejicano, tradicionalmente la primera persona singular del verbo *ser* era *seigo*:

> Hola, ¿Quién eres?
>   — **Seigo** Juan.

Siguiendo el modelo normal, en el que esta forma comparte raíz con el presente del subjuntivo, también son diferentes las formas propias de ese modo:

> No creo que ella **seiga** la hija de María.

Por la pérdida del idioma castellano en mediados del siglo XX y la recuperación del mismo unas décadas después por influencia mejicana, esta forma ya es, desgraciadamente, moribunda.

Answer (score 2):

En la segunda persona singular informal o de formalidad intermedia (*tú*) del pretérito indefinido (o pretérito perfecto simple), las terminaciones regulares pueden variar geográficamente.

Muchos saben de la terminación con *-s* (*nadastes*, etcétera), propia del voseo y muy mal vista en dialectos tuteantes, pero hay otra:

> ¿Quieres ir a la piscina o ya *nadates*?
>   ¿Tienes hambre o ya *comites*?
>   ¿Ya *escribites* la carta a tu novia?

Es decir, en la primera conjugación, en vez de *-aste*, tenemos **-ates**, y en la segunda y tercera conjugación, tenemos *iste* tenemos **-ites**.

Cosa parecida occure en la segunda persona plural informal en el dialecto andaluz, y puede subir la vocal átono a /i/: *-atis* / *-itis*

Answer (score 1):

En México, en el campo, se dice

> fuistes

en lugar de

> fuiste

con todos los verbos, no solo *ir*.