# ¿Existen verbos que puedan ser al mismo tiempo regulares e irregulares?

Tags: verbos, solicitud-de-término, conjugación

Por lo general, los verbos en español se clasifican como regulares (siguen una conjugación modelo) o irregulares (su conjugación no sigue ningún modelo general, aunque pequeños grupos de verbos pueden seguir patrones similares). Sin embargo, ¿existe algún verbo que pueda ser regular e irregular al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Relacionada: [Diferencias regionales en las conjugaciones de los verbos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21298/5481), que viene a ser muy parecida a esta pregunta pero bajo la óptica de las diferencias regionales (el mismo verbo conjugado como regular o irregular en distintas variantes regionales). Mi pregunta venía motivada por la diferencia al formar el participio de "learn" (learnt/learned - idem con _burnt/burned_ y otros) dependiendo de la variante del inglés.

Comment: Con distintas etimologías y en proceso de unificación: los dos [_asolar_](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=asolar).

Answer (score 2):

El verbo *acostar* puede ser regular o irregular, según su significado:

> **[acostar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0a2LFsQ)**
>
> De *costa*<sup>2</sup>.
>   Conjug. actual c. *contar*, salvo en acep. 6, que es reg.

La acepción 6 indicada es la siguiente:

> 6. intr. Llegar a la costa.

Por tanto, en todas sus demás acepciones la conjugación debe mudar la *o* en *ue* en los casos pertinentes: *acuesto*, *acueste*, salvo que se use el verbo para el uso de "llegar a la costa", en cuyo caso se diría *acosto*, *acoste*.

Este es el único caso de verbo regular e irregular en el que en ambos casos se proviene de la misma etimología. Existe al menos otro verbo (o puede que alguno más) al que le pasa lo mismo, pero las formas regular e irregular provienen de etimologías diferentes:

> [**aforar<sup>1</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0zo7hda%7C0zq9GyG)
>
> De *a-*<sup>1</sup> y *foro*.
>
> [**aforar<sup>2</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0zo7hda%7C0zq9GyG)
>
> De *a-*<sup>1</sup> y *fuero*.
>   Conjug. c. contar.

Comment: roer: roo/royo/roigo

Answer (score 2):

Se podrían agregar también los verbos con doble participio. Dice la RAE:

> [Dobles participios: imprimido/impreso, freído/frito, proveído/provisto](https://www.rae.es/consultas/dobles-participios-imprimidoimpreso-freidofrito-proveidoprovisto)
>
> Los únicos verbos que en la lengua actual presentan dos participios, uno regular y otro irregular, son imprimir (imprimido/impreso), freír (freído/frito) y proveer (proveído/provisto), con sus respectivos derivados.

Answer (score 2):

Errar es otro. En América es un verbo regular principalmente.